# Minecraft Datapack advancements not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I was making a custom achievement, but the funtion in the reward doesn't run when the conditions are met. The advancement does grant appear in the `/advancement` command and it does grant the reward when I manually grant the achievement, but it doesn't grant the reward when not doing it manually.

**Advancement JSON**

```
{
    "criteria": {
        "glass_breaker": {
            "trigger": "minecraft:recipe_unlocked",
            "conditions": {
                "recipe": "room:glass_breaker_crafted"
            }
        }
    },
    "rewards": {
        "function": "room:crafted_glass_breaker"
    }
}
```

I have it so when the achievement is unlocked it will run a function that gives the player the custom item then revokes the advancement.

Answer (score 1):

This advancement seems like it is supposed to trigger when the recipe is unlocked, but is there another advancement that allows it to be unlocked? That was an issue I ran into early on. There needs to be another advancement that triggers when a condition is met (say, collecting stone) that grants the recipe. You can test this with `/recipe give @a *`

Also it needs to be in your own room namespace. Assuming the formatting is correct, it does seem that it should trigger when the recipe is unlocked.